# Zap scan returns no alerts on a subsequent scan

Tags: api, owasp, zap

I am using the OWASP ZAP scanning tool using its API. I ran an active scan against my website and it created four alerts. However, minutes later, on the second run it returned 0 alerts. It seems like it saved the earlier alerts somewhere and only looked for new ones. My question is, how to reset ZAP so that it starts a scan afresh, with no knowledge of prior scan results. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset Zap, you can create a new session using the [core](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ApiGen_core) API.

Also notice that you need to wait until Zap's complete the scan, this could also lead to inconsistent results. Check out this [implementatio](https://github.com/OWASP/glue/blob/master/lib/glue/tasks/zap.rb) as a reference to what needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am waiting for a scan to complete, but I can't get the location of the session file (to use in a call for new session). I am using python API and session_location returns blank.

Comment: api methods for session file and session snapshot do not return anything. I call those methods after I start  an active scan. Thanks

Comment: I restarted the docker container with "-newsession path_to_file" option to be able to overwrite it when I start a new scan - that did the trick. Accepting your answer for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Thanks. I would also check that the scan actually completes, I've spent a few hours figuring out why the scan results were inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks. I would also check that the scan actually completes, I've spent a few hours figuring out why the scan results were inconsistent.